# Setting nav to fixed after scrolling to a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, bulma

I'm designing a landing page using a Flexbox based CSS Framework - [Bulma](https://bulma.io/).

I created a navbar below a fullheight section and I'm using it to scroll through sections, which gets fixed/unfixed depending whether the page is scrolled *below the fullheight section*.
This is the JQuery code I'm using to add/remove the fixed position class:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#cover').height()) {
        $('#navbar-sticky').addClass('is-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('#cover').height()) {
        $('#navbar-sticky').removeClass('is-fixed');
    }
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that when the navigation bar is set to `position: relative` - default position, when clicking on any link to a section it "overscrolls" using the height of the navigation bar.

Another issue is that when navigating to the first section - where the class is toggled, there's also an overscroll, I believe using `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#cover').height())` (is greater than or equal to) fixes that.

Here's a relevant codepen that describes my issue https://codepen.io/miraris/full/wrLdwN
I'm also using a [smooth-scroll library](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) in that codepen, but that's irrelevant and the issue is the same when it's removed (just no offset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element's position is changed to Fixed, a portion equal to it's height is freed from DOM and elements below it shift up.

We can have a wrapper to fill the space created by navbar becoming fixed.

**Html**

```
<div class="navbar-space-fill hidden"></div>
<div id="navbar-sticky">
.... your HTML ....
</div>
```

**Javascript**

On page load-

```
$('.navbar-space-fill').css({'height':$('#navbar-sticky').height()});
```

When position of navbar becomes fixed -

```
$('.navbar-space-fill').removeClass('hidden');
```

else -

```
$(".navbar-space-fill").addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. Do you know any resources I could read through on this topic? I didn't find anything yet about this.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the nav at the top of the window it looks like you just need to remove the offset property.

`var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {});`

Comment: It does indeed scroll correctly when the navbar position is set to fixed already, but not when it's being changed as @inaitgaJ describes.